# How to remove validation from a jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this script from a tutorial but I don't want the validation part, just the posting part.. I tried to delete the validation related commands but it doesn't work. Maybe I did it wrongly, but my thought is if all of these are needed to run the submitHandler.

Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            message: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please let us know who you are.",
            email: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you.",
            message: "Please write a subject."
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.post('mailme.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#results').hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If all you want to do is submit the form then all you need is the code in the submitHandler. $.post(...

Comment: Interesting, you wanna use the validate plugin, but you don't want to validate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use the .validate() function then.  You probably want to use .post() to submit the form: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/